# How to make an Authentification using EF and MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have an interface for the LOG ON (connection) but it is not related to my base where i have a USER table (contain Login + password).

The problem is that I can't change the way that of connection. Precisly, I want thr connection will be related to my base.

It's difficult because I use an Entity Framework and Code First method.

Is there any solution ?

This my View Log On :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"%>
    <p>

        S'il vous plaît entrer votre Login et Mot de Passe pour vous connecter :
    </p>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account")) { %>
        <table>
            <tr><td><label for="username" style="width:10em">Matricule :</label></td><td><%= Html.TextBox("Matricule") %><%= Html.ValidationMessage("Matricule") %></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label for="password" style="width:10em">Mot de passe:</label></td><td><%= Html.Password("passWord") %><%= Html.ValidationMessage("passWord") %></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><%= Html.CheckBox("rememberMe") %> <label for="rememberMe">Se souvenir de moi ?</label></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Se Connecter" /></td></tr>
        </table>
<% } %>
```

and this the Controller :

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string Matricule, string passWord, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ValidateLogOn(Matricule, passWord))
            {
                return View();
            }

            FormsAuth.SignIn(Matricule, rememberMe);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

---

Thanks For the Answer,
First, I am not using WEB API.
My application is an ASP MVC 3 application with C# and using a SQL SERVER 2005 Database.
Second, I will try to explain more :
I created an Internet Application (New Project-->ASP .NET MVC 3 WEB APPLICATION--> Internet Application).
As you know, when you created an Internet Application, VS created to you a way to LogOn and Register using Cookies.
I created my database using Entity Framework 4 and Code First (created many models which will be generated as Tables in my base).
So, I have a Table User which contains A Nom (Login) + Password. 
I would like that when I enter the login and the password in my Web Inerface (textBox), the editor verify if they are conforme or no (exist) in the table User.

This my model User :

```
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Matricule :")]
        public string Matricule { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom :")]
        public string Nom_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Le {0} doit avoir au minimum {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Mot de passe :")]
        public string passWord { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Account")]
        [Display(Name = "Type :")]
        public string Type_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("UF")]
        [Display(Name = "ID UF :")]
        public string ID_UF { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual UF UF { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the Context file  :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class GammeContext : DbContext
    {
        public GammeContext()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GammeContext>());

        }


        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ns_AFaire> Ns_AFaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Famille> Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction> Fonctions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction_Poste> Fonction_Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gamme> Gammes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Historique> Historiques { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ligne> Lignes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile_Ga> Profil_Gas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sous_Famille> Sous_Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UF> UFs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Num_Serie> Num_Series { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean: Can you create an instance of the `EntityModel` inside your `Action` logic? Also could you give a *simple* layout of your database model?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,,,,if i understand you right, this is the instance of my Entity model : private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();
Sorry for the layout, i still don't have the permession to post images,,,but it is simple, you just need to know that i have a table USER (Login, pwd, name,..) and this is table which i need to verify that a user can connect or not? I hope that you understand me better now

Comment: Could you please describe your problem better :) You can update your question btw. Do you need help with `ValidateLogOn`?

Comment: Looks like you're using Web Api with EF, if so check out this tutorial http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-with-afa30545 ... if that sorts you out then maybe delete this post. Skills You’ll Learn: How to use forms authentication with Web API to authenticate users.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer,
First, I am not using WEB API.
Second, I will try to explain more : I created an Internet Application (New Project-->ASP.NET MVC 3 WEB APPLICATION--> Internet Application).
As you know, when you created an Internet Application, VS created to you a way to LogOn and Register using Cookies.
I created my database using Entity Framework 4 and Code First 
So, I have a Table User which contains A Nom (Login)+ Password. 

I found in a some forum that is IMPOSSIBLE to Access to the database when you use Entity Framework ?
Is that true ?? and if is YES, what is the solution ?